# indexPath.row returns properly with didSelectRow, but not with accessoryButtonTapped?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editInfo" sender:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editInfo"]) {
        EditInfoViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
        NSLog(@"%d",selectedIndex);
        [vc setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sendMessage"]) {
                 ...
    }
}
```

The selectedIndex variable is always NSLogged as 0... Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tapping a UITableViewCell's accessoryButton doesn't select the row containing the accessoryButton.

When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you could pass `indexPath` as the `sender`, which you could then reference in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: In accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editInfo" sender:indexPath] ;` . In prepareForSegue: `NSLog(@"%d", [sender row]) ;`