# UITableView - didSelectRowAtIndexPath only fires when label is tapped

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have a simple tableView. If I tap on the label (left side), didSelectRowAtIndexPath fires ok. It does not fire when I tap on the right side (textField).

I cannot figure what I'm missing.. My code to create and select the cells is as follows:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    currentIndexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"didSelect currentIndexPath.section is %i", currentIndexPath.section);
    NSLog(@"didSelect currentIndexPath.row is %i", currentIndexPath.row);
}
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is by design. Tapping inside a UITextField that is in a row doesn't automatically select the row. If your rows have Accessory Buttons, [tapping them doesn't select the row, either.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14016136/1523962)

*Edit*

If you'd like to know the index path of the TableViewCell that contains the active TextField, add this to your textFieldShould/DidBeginEditing:

```
id cellContainingFirstResponder = textField.superview.superview ;
NSIndexPath* indexPathContainingFirstResponder = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cellContainingFirstResponder] ;
```

Comment: Hi John +1 for trying to help me. But selectRowAtIndexPath does not allow me to identify the row. I've tried that in textFieldShould and textFieldDidBeginEditing.. What about building a custom cell?

Comment: John, thanks - I log cellContainingFirstResponder but it returns NULL.

Comment: I got it.. Not sure why, but this works: id cellContainingFirstResponder = textField.superview; so many thanks John, I will mark this as the correct answer.. woohoo.

Comment: Great! `textField.superview` used to work for me, but I've found in my recent projects that textField's superview is the Cell's `contentView`, and the `contentView`'s superview is the Cell.